# How to convert list of dictionaries to dataframe using pandas in python

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I have a list of dictionaries:
`data = [{'name': 'peter', 'id': 92, 'value': 6500},{'name': 'peter', 'id': 93, 'value': 6000`},[{'name': 'jack', 'id': 93, 'value': 9500}]

and I want it to be converted to a dataframe:

```
peter    id   jack 
6500     92  0/NaN
6000     93   9500
```

How to do that in python.

I have tried this but it is not working

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,  columns =['name', 'value']) 
print (df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just doing this?

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

It gives you:

```
    name    id  value
0   peter   92  6500
1   jack    93  6000
```